# accessing function result within another function

Tags: jquery

I have the function `isRetina` below, and I'm trying to access the result within another `resizeImage()` but the variable retinaCheck always gives me back undefined. I declared the global variable at the start, why would that be?

```
 $(window).load(function () {
     function isRetina() {
         return ((window.matchMedia && (window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx), only screen and (min-resolution: 75.6dpcm)').matches || window.matchMedia('only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)').matches)) || (window.devicePixelRatio && window.devicePixelRatio > 2)) && /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent);
     }

     var retinaCheck = isRetina();

 });

 function resizeImage() {
     if ($(window).width() > 649) {
         console.log("resize:" + retinaCheck)

     }
 });
```

Comment: Works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/rx0khzp0/1/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Without code that reproduces the issue (which, your code doesn't do - try it in a snipper) - there is little we can do to help you.

Comment: `var retinaCheck = isRetina();` is not global in your case, it exists inside .load only

Comment: @user1937021 please format it.

Comment: JavaScript has function scope - your `isRetina` variable is local to your `"load"` handler.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - this user has over 220 (!) questions - I don't think you should have to format his code. I'm sure they can do it themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a global variable outside `window.load` and assign value to it inside `window.load`. When you call `resizeImage()` function you can read retinaCheck value.

```
var retinaCheck;
 $(window).load(function() {
    function isRetina(){
         return ((window.matchMedia && (window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx), only screen and (min-resolution: 75.6dpcm)').matches || window.matchMedia('only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)').matches)) || (window.devicePixelRatio && window.devicePixelRatio > 2)) && /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent);
    }

    retinaCheck = isRetina();

});

function resizeImage() {
   if ($(window).width() > 649) {        
          console.log("resize:"+retinaCheck)            
      });
}
```

Comment: He has already defined retinaCheck as a global variable.

Comment: How would that make a difference? Even if there is a scenario in which this fixes the issue - providing this answer without nay context is not very helpful - please consider expanding it.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar you haven't explained anything, only now it contains a syntax error. Please consider improving it.